# Overlay two images and center in a div, CSS only

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to play a gif on hover by hiding the png to show the gif behind. I can play the gif on hover, the problem is that it's not centered in the div.
I tried it here :

```
https://codepen.io/yumamri/pen/rNjyPpb
```

```
<h2>
  Animation
</h2>
<div class="image_container">
  <img class="static" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5478103/pexels-photo-5478103.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">
  <img class="active" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/6329084/pexels-photo-6329084.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260">
</div>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

```
.static {
  position:absolute;
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  display:block;
}

.static:hover {
  opacity:0;
}

.active {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.static, .active {
    height: 500px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #EF233C;
}
```

Comment: Your codepen example is not working

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://codepen.io/Bertw/pen/xxgqBRR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to center ? "image container" ? if then try this

```
.image_container{
 display: flex;
 flex-direction:column or row (if needed);
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 height: 100vh
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked perfectly! I didn't need the flex-direction nor the height, it adjusted to the center based on the content.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the effect you wish either by making the image_container div have a position: relative, and adding the images in it floating in the center, if you try to align them they will not overlay or be over each other.

I modified your code hope this helps:

```css
.image_container {
 position: relative;
 min-height: 520px;
 width: 333px;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.static {
  position:absolute;
  background: white;
  margin: auto;
  display:block;      
  z-index: 2;
}

.static:hover {
  opacity:0;
}

.active {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;        
}

.static, .active {
    height: 500px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #EF233C;
}
```

```html
<h2>
  Animation
</h2>
<div class="image_container">
  <img class="static" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/5478103/pexels-photo-5478103.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260">
  <img class="active" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/6329084/pexels-photo-6329084.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260">
</div>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
  Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```